# Possibility of displaying the clock on Windows 10

Tags: windows

I recently upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10, and i really miss the clock on the task bar.

Is it possible to display a clock in the task bar like with previous version?

Comment: <scratches head> there is a clock in the task bar in Windows 10

Comment: Not for me. Is there meant to be one there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings > System >Notifications and actions > Turn system icons on or off

[image]